# Custom SOLR Data Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I'm really having trouble with the JPA repository initialization using Spring Data Solr repository. I'm trying to add a custom repository for building a dynamic query. I've read a few stack overflow and other links that suggest the problem is that I'm not following the right naming convention for my custom repository. Ref: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-78

But I can't see what's wrong with my implementation, I've tried all manner of combinations! It keeps reporting that "property search not found" because it's trying to instantiate the query instead of recognising the custom implementation. Can anyone else suggest what's wrong with this?

This is a summary of the class and interface structure:

```
//custom interface definition
public interface CustomerDocumentRepositoryCustom {

  public List<CustomerDocument> search(String searchTerm, String sortBy, 
    int pageSize, HashMap<String, Object> facets, Pageable page);
}

// I've tried "CustomerDocumentRepositoryCustomImpl" and tried adding the Repository annotation here
public class CustomerDocumentRepositoryImpl implements CustomerDocumentRepositoryCustom {

  @Resource
  private SolrTemplate solrTemplate1;

  @Override
  public List<CustomerDocument> search(String searchTerm, String sortBy, 
    int pageSize, HashMap<String, Object> facets, Pageable page) {
  …
  }
}

/**
 * This is the SOLR repository handler
 */
public interface CustomerSolrCrudRepositoryImpl extends CustomerDocumentRepositoryCustom,
  SolrCrudRepository<CustomerDocument, String> {

    @Query("text:?0")
    public List<CustomerDocument> findByText(String searchString);
}
```

The relevant part of the startup stack trace is below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property search found for type CustomerDocument!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[PropertyPath.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[Part.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213) ~[PartTree$OrPart.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321) ~[PartTree$Predicate.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301) ~[PartTree$Predicate.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:82) ~[PartTree.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.PartTreeSolrQuery.<init>(PartTreeSolrQuery.java:36) ~[PartTreeSolrQuery.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(SolrRepositoryFactory.java:130) ~[SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224) ~[RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210) ~[RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.class:?]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66) ~[SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.class:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:446) ~[CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420) ~[CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155) ~[InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh never mind, I figured it out eventually. I had to rename the base repository to `CustomerDocumentRepository` and it started working.

This convention is so unclear in the documentation for custom repositories! All it mentions is add `Impl` to the implementation of the custom class.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I've just re-checked the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) and they're pretty precise about the naming and show all the important parts. Anything particular that you were missing?

Comment: It is there, but it needs to call out that the names of the interfaces are important. When I read it, it sounds like they're examples only. But it seems you need the it to be Main interface = <RepoName>, Custom interface = <RepoNameCustom> & Custom Implementation = <RepoNameImpl> to make it work. When I read it, I only interpreted that the important part was to name the custom interface and implementation class need to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've filed [DATACMNS-552](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-552) to fix that.